# Term for verb+adverb with distinct meaning

Tags: verbs, terminology, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

There are verbs that, when paired with certain adverbs, can have a distinctly different meaning.  For example,

> I *looked up* the word in the dictionary.

The phrase *looked up* functions as a verb with a distinct meaning than *looked* in a sentence like

> I *looked* ridiculous.

In all of these two-word verb examples I can think of, they become a single word when used as a noun or adjective:

> The software performs millions of lookups per second.

Is there a term for these verb+adverb pairs, and, if so, what is it?

Additional examples:  *back up*, *run off*, *hang out*

Once upon a time, I though these were called *verbals*, but that was wrong.  The term *verb phrase* is not quite right either; a verb phrase generally encompasses additional modifiers, objects, etc.

Comment: Yes. They're called [Phrasal Verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/EnglishPhrasalVerbs.pdf). There are several different kinds, with different properties and meanings. They're idiomatic, and there are more of them than there are of non-phrasal verbs. (And, by the way, the particle isn't always an adverb)

Comment: There are 144 questions on this site which actually have the tag [tag:phrasal-verbs], and twice as many which [mention](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=phrasal+verb) them

Comment: @John Lawler: Thanks!  Phrasal verb is the term I was looking for.  Particle is a new one to me though, more research to do.

Comment: "Particle" is a non-question-begging term to refer to the non-verb part of a phrasal verb. "Verb plus particle constructions" or "two-word verbs" are terms that have been used for them. They work sort of like German separable prefixes (_trennbare Vorsilben_), but have different morphology and syntax, of course.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth:  Seems a stretch to call this a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look is a verb, while look up is a [phrasal verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb).

> The term phrasal verb is commonly applied to two or three distinct but
>   related constructions in English: a verb and a particle and/or a
>   preposition co-occur forming a single semantic unit. This semantic
>   unit cannot be understood based upon the meanings of the individual
>   parts in isolation, but rather it must be taken as a whole. In other
>   words, the meaning is non-compositional and thus unpredictable.